# Why did Abraham and Isaac instruct their children to marry only from their clan?

Tags: abraham, isaac, canaan

Abraham was from a pagan family, separated by his call to God. His families I supposed weren't different from the Canaanites in pagan worship. In some instances, the Canaanites proved more morally upright than Abraham and Isaac by instructing their fellows not to interfere with Isaac and Abraham's wives (family), meeting with dire consequences anyone who does break such binding law. Genesis 24:3 -

> and I will have you swear by the LORD, the God of heaven and the God
> of earth, that you will not take a wife for my son from the daughters
> of the Canaanites among whom I am dwelling

If this proves true, why did Abraham and Isaac instruct the heirs of the covenant never to marry from the Canaanites (pagans) but should marry from their families (pagans) in Padan-Aram?

Comment: As I commented in SE-C : after his call from God, Abraham (as a result of that call from God himself) was no longer a 'pagan' and this is the reason for his, and for subsequent, separation. I don't understand what it is that you are trying to find out. When God calls, he calls _out_ from that which is not of himself.

Comment: See also: [Why did Abraham insist that Isaac marry from his kinfolk in Genesis 24?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/75923/why-did-abraham-insist-that-isaac-marry-from-his-kinfolk-in-genesis-24?rq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did Abraham insist that Isaac marry from his kinfolk in Genesis 24?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/75923/why-did-abraham-insist-that-isaac-marry-from-his-kinfolk-in-genesis-24)

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to this question:

1. **Paganism**

The premise of this question is factually untrue.  Abraham's family, from whom Rebekah came, were not as "pagan" as suggested - they clearly worshipped Jehovah as can be seen in Gen 24 where the name Jehovah in the Hebrew occurs 19 times and spoken by Laban as well such V21, 50, 51, etc.

2. **Selecting a wife vs Living**

It was precisely because Abrahm's relatives were worshipers of the Jehovah that the servant was sent to find a wife for Isaac among them.  However, we should also not that while they were worshipers of Jehovah, that worship was presumably imperfect or incomplete because Abraham instructed the servant that under no circumstances was Isaac allowed to go and live among them - see V6.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dottard has already said, Abraham's clan would no longer be considered pagan upon their worship of God. '[Pagan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paganism#Nomenclature_and_etymology)' was a term created by Christians to describe polytheists, translating to something like calling someone a 'rustic' with a somewhat insulting connotation.

### Stopped the spread of paganism

As to the reasoning of the instruction to not marry pagans, this can be seen in the explanations of the similar command given later. This was done partly for practical reasons to stop paganism from spreading to the Jews:

> Do not intermarry with them. Do not give your daughters to their sons or take their daughters for your sons, for they will turn your children away from following me to serve other gods... (Deut. 7:3 NIV)

> [W]e have forsaken Your commandments, which You commanded by Your servants the prophets, saying, 'The land which you are entering to possess is an unclean land, with the uncleanness of the peoples of the lands, with their abominations which have filled it from one end to another with their impurity. Now therefore, do not give your daughters as wives for their sons, nor take their daughters to your sons... (Ezr. 9:11 NIV)

Indeed this warning comes true later in the Old Testament:

> King Solomon, however, loved many foreign women besides Pharaoh’s daughter—Moabites, Ammonites, Edomites, Sidonians and Hittites. They were ... from nations about which the Lord had told the Israelites, "You must not intermarry with them, because they will surely turn your hearts after their gods." Nevertheless, Solomon held fast to them in love. ... his wives led him astray. As Solomon grew old, his wives turned his heart after other gods, and his heart was not fully devoted to the Lord his God... (1 Kgs. 11:1 NIV)

> [King Ahab] not only considered it trivial to commit the sins of Jeroboam son of Nebat, but he also married Jezebel daughter of Ethbaal king of the Sidonians, and began to serve Baal and worship him. (1 Kgs. 16:31 NIV)

This becomes a generational problem for the children of the marriage:

> [King Jehoram] followed the ways of the kings of Israel, as the house of Ahab had done, for he married a daughter of Ahab. He did evil in the eyes of the Lord. (2 Kgs. 8:18)

In Kings, a pagan queen is often indirectly referred to as the cause of paganism in the country by influencing her husband and his rule, not entirely unlike the children of families like Ahab's:

> [King Rehoboam son of Solomon] mother’s name was Naamah; she was an Ammonite. Judah did evil in the eyes of the Lord. By the sins they committed they stirred up his jealous anger more than those who were before them had done. They also set up for themselves high places, sacred stones and Asherah poles... (1 Kgs. 14:22)

Paul also reiterates this purpose in the **New Testament**, (addressing belief and no longer ethnicity) stressing that a believer should not marry an unbeliever so as not to have their own righteousness corrupted by the unbeleivers sin.

> Do not be unequally yoked together with unbelievers. For what fellowship has righteousness with lawlessness? And what communion has light with darkness? And what accord has Christ with Belial? ... And what agreement has the temple of God with idols? For you are the temple of the living God. ... (2 Cor. 6:14 NIV)

### Promoted ceremonial holiness

Additionally, I would argue that the prohibition of marriage to the Canaanites was also to promote a ceremonial separation between the Israelites and the other people groups (especially as Israel represented God to the world in their behavior). That is to say, to separate yourself from something for the purpose of ascribing meaning to the cause for which you do so. If the prohibition against intermarriage is only religious, why would it then be prohibited to marry a righteous pagan willing to faithfully convert to Judaism rather than an extremely sinful and unfaithful Israelite? As you say, some pagans may have been more morally upright than Abraham's family. This is best seen in Ezra, as Ezra confronts the exiles returning from the Babylonian Captivity for intermarriage:

> Now therefore, make confession to the Lord God of your fathers, and do His will; **separate yourselves** from the peoples of the land, and from the pagan wives. (Ezr. 10:11 NIV)

The concept of separate-ness is often invoked as a descriptor or synonym of holiness.

> Then [Moses] said to Him, "If Your Presence does not go with us, do not bring us up from here. For how then will it be known that Your people and I have found grace in Your sight, except **You go with us? So we shall be separate**, Your people and I, from all the people who are upon the face of the earth." (Ex. 33:16 NIV)

> And **you shall be holy** to Me, **for I** the Lord am holy, and **have separated you** from the peoples, that you should be Mine. (Lev. 20:26 NIV)

> ... When either a man or woman consecrates an offering to take the vow of a Nazirite, to separate himself to the LORD ... **All the days of** the vow of **his separation** ... for which he separated himself to the LORD, **he shall be holy**... (Num. 6:2 NIV)

> Thus you shall separate the Levites from among the children of Israel, and the Levites shall be Mine. (Num. 6:6 NIV)

The prohibition of intermarriage therefore promoted an increased separation between the Israelites and the other peoples, and so also by virtue of the meaning ascribed to this separation by Israel's commitment to follow the rule, increased the special nature of their relationship to God as His people.

In the **New Testament**, the prohibition against intermarriage based on ethnicity is no longer in force due to Christ's death obsoleting the distinction between Israelites and non-Israelites insofar as it allowed all people to directly commune with God (Lk. 23:45, Rev. 5:5), and insofar as it fulfilled the Mosaic law (Mth. 5:17) in that the specifics of the law no longer have to be followed as they have been superseded by the general standard of God's perfection to which the original laws pointed (Mth. 5:48). Paul, after speaking against marriage to unbelievers, reaffirms the value of separate-ness, but speaks of it in terms of individual righteousness rather than an ethnicity's holiness:

> Therefore go out from their [the unbelievers'] midst,
> and **be separate from them**, says the Lord,
> and touch no unclean thing;
> then I will welcome you ... (2 Cor 6:16, see Isa. 52:11)

### Conclusion

Prohibition against marriage with pagans or Canaanites was for the practical purpose of stopping the spread of paganism among the Israelites, and also for the spiritual purpose of providing an increased separation for the Israelites to ascribe them holiness as God's chosen people.